# How to execute a Javascript function inside WKWebview?

Tags: javascript, webview, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

## Hello community,

I am stuck with this problem for days and I couldn't find any solutions, maybe you can help me out..

I created an App that uses the WKWebview to connect to a website. The login happens native on iOS, after the user issued their credentials, i want to Login on the webpage as well.

Therefore my Webpage has a Javascript function called "handleLogin" where i receive the credentials and the user does not have to login again and is directly fowarded to his main page.

### Now I want to call handleLogin() from native code inside my WKWebview.

I already tried several ways, on Android it can easily be done with:

> view.LoadUrl("javascript:(handleLogin(placeholder))");

In iOS I already tried it inside
`public override async void DidFinishNavigation(WKWebView webView, WKNavigation navigation)`
with:

> await webView.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("handleLogin(credentialsPlaceholder);");

but the only result i get is an exception:

```
Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=0, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: undefined is not a function, WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=0, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}'
```

Can it be that I have to wait longer until everything is loaded?
I am sure that handleLogin exists, testet it on Android as well as in browsers, how can it be undefined?
Does EvaluateJavascript work only on internal scripts?

I hope you can help me out,
Kind regards

Comment: Hi , you mean that `handleLogin` exists in webview , and native ios need to response it ? You can have a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559483/xamarin-ios-communication-between-javascript-and-c-sharp) .

Comment: Basically yes, handleLogin already exists in the webview, I can access it from Android as well as from console inside the safari browser. Unfortunately EvaluateJavascript tells me that this method is undefined, even if it clearly isn't.

Already looked into the discussion, I implemented it as such, but my wkwebview seems to handle it differently..

Comment: You can have a try with local html file to check whether it works first ,maybe website not supports the javascript .

Comment: Yeah, I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

Found some information that might help

source: [read more](https://medium.com/capital-one-tech/javascript-manipulation-on-ios-using-webkit-2b1115e7e405)

**User Scripts**

The WKUserScript object, when added to the userContentController, allows developers to take JavaScript and inject it into a webpage. Here’s a simple example of adding a script to change the background color of the Google web page from above:

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()
let scriptSource = "document.body.style.backgroundColor = `red`;"
let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptSource, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
contentController.addUserScript(script)

let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
config.userContentController = contentController

let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! The thing is, i don't actually want to add or inject Javascript, I just want to call an already existing function on the website. HandleLogin is on the webviews side and i just want to call it..

There is no need to alter or inject scripts :/