# sfsafariviewcontroller handling permissions requests

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to access the camera and microphone for a webview displayed in a SFSafariViewController.

I think I should respond to camera and microphone access requests made by the browser but I can't find a way to do it.

On Android we have an override in WebChromeClient to do exactly that:

```
public override void OnPermissionRequest(PermissionRequest request)
{
    request.Grant(new String[] { PermissionRequest.ResourceAudioCapture, PermissionRequest.ResourceVideoCapture });
}
```

Do I have any chance to no being forced to fallback to using Safari Directly instead of SFSafariViewController?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, `SFSafariViewController` can not do that . You can use webview to call native code to access permissions .

Comment: Do you know any example that I can start with?

Comment: Sorry , I have no direct sample to explain that .That's only half part of work , the left work need to transfer the data from camera and audio to webview . Maybe you can refer to this discussion to start with . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36559483/xamarin-ios-communication-between-javascript-and-c-sharp